# how to use cubic interpolation in ceres solver

Tags: c++, interpolation, cubic-spline, ceres-solver

It’s my first time to use ceres to optimize my project, i know it not very well. wenn I follow example to write my project, it is not compilable. here is my code and my error (black one)and the code what i found in Gitlab(white one).

u,v is pixel coordinated,. Datatyp of m_Mask is 
vector(Cv::Mat).
I want to get the mask value, (1 or 0) and gray value(int) by u,v pixel. Can I write my code like this , what means Here .ptr(0)? 
Looking for your replay. Thank you! :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLirQ.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oku54.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VrnG.png)

Best regard

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use text rather than images. Images are unreachable by too may people, unviewable by many more, cannot be compiled with compilers in regular use, and are much harder for future questioners to search.

Comment: When you add text, construct a [mre]. Often just constructing the MRE will allow you to see and solve the problem, but if You're still stuck, it allows us to compile your code and poke around at it to offer solutions that not only compile but also do what you want. Any fool can get rid of a compiler error an unhelpful way, but that makes for a bad answer.